# Replacing backslash in content with Low Replace

Tags: low-replace, regex

I am currently using Low Replace to clean up content exported from EE to be used as a JSON object. This means cleaning up new lines, spaces, escaping quotes and backslashes. I am able to get the first three to work. However I cannot seem to find a way to escape a backslash.

I've even tried to map it as a replacement option in pi.low_replace.php

```
private $_map = array(
        'SPACE'   => ' ',
        'QUOTE'   => '"',
        'NEWLINE' => "\n",
        'PIPE'    => '|',
        'BACKSLASH'    => "\\"
    );
```

No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

```
'BACKSLASH'    => "\/"
```

Also found out I didn't need to modify the plugin.

```
{exp:low_replace multiple='yes' regex='yes' find='\/|QUOTE|NEWLINE|/\t/' replace='\|\QUOTE|SPACE'}
```

Works like a charm.